# Crond execute shell many times

Tags: shell, cron

I have the following `timey.cpp` code in RedHat 2.6.32 x86_64:

```
using namespace std ;
int main()
{
    while( 1 ){
        char x[64]={0} ;
        strcpy( x,"1234567890") ;
        std::string s = x ;
        std::cout << "(" <<  x << ")" << std::endl ;
        struct timeval localtimex ;
        long secs,usecs ;
        gettimeofday(&localtimex,0x00) ;
        secs  = localtimex.tv_sec ;
        usecs = localtimex.tv_usec ;
        //long mills = (time.tv_sec * 1000) + (time.tv_usec / 1000 ) ;
        printf("secs=(%d),usecs=(%d)\n",secs,usecs) ;
        sleep( 1 ) ;
    } //while 
}
```

in `/home/informix/test`, compiled by `g++ --std=c++0x timey.cpp -o timey.exe`,
and the shell `timey.sh`:

```
    source /etc/bashrc
    nohup /home/informix/test/timey.exe &
```

Then I run `timey.sh` by:

```
    /home/informix/test/timey.sh
```

and take a look if `timey.exe` runs by:

```
    ps -ef | grep timey
```

It seems `timey.exe` runs as expected:

```
    informix 41340     1  0 10:32 pts/10   00:00:00 /home/informix/test/timey.exe
```

What confuses me is that I add this shell to crontab:

```
    38 10 * * 1-5 informix /home/informix/test/timey.sh
```

and restart `crond`:

```
    /etc/init.d/crond restart
```

What surprises me is I see 4 copies of `timey.exe` running:

```
    ps -ef | grep timey
    informix 41498     1  0 10:38 ?        00:00:00 /home/informix/test/timey.exe
    informix 41499     1  0 10:38 ?        00:00:00 /home/informix/test/timey.exe
    informix 41529     1  0 10:38 ?        00:00:00 /home/informix/test/timey.exe
    informix 41561     1  0 10:38 ?        00:00:00 /home/informix/test/timey.exe
```

What did I do wrong so that 4 copies of `timey.exe` are running?

I see the following in `/var/log/cron`:

```
Jul  2 10:38:01 localhost CROND[41440]: (informix) CMD (/home/informix/test/timey.sh )
Jul  2 10:38:01 localhost CROND[41439]: (informix) CMD (/home/informix/test/timey.sh )
Jul  2 10:38:01 localhost CROND[41491]: (informix) CMD (/home/informix/test/timey.sh )
Jul  2 10:38:01 localhost CROND[41533]: (informix) CMD (/home/informix/test/timey.sh )
```

It seems that `crond` really ran `timey.sh` 4 times, but why?

Also:

- In RedHat 2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64, it works!
- In RedHat 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64, it does not work!

Comment: It is curious that you have the four processes all with the same start time.  It also appears you must be somewhere in (eastern?) Asia to have times on 2015-07-02 when it is still 2015-07-01 in the western USA.  Are you sure you don't have 4 copies of the cron daemon running?  Your program doesn't exit, so once one copy is started, it continues to run indefinitely, so if the copies were started a day apart, there'd be no surprise.  But all at the same time is surprising.

Comment: Have you run `crontab -l` to check that the new entry isn't in the file 4 times?